# Publish ASP.NET website + database to Windows Azure Websites

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I've signed up for a test account on Windows Azure to test it out. I build a Hello world ASP.NET web application + database just for testing.

I installed Visual Studio 2012 RC and installed the Windows Azure software.

In Windows Azure I've created a new Website e+ Database, I think that is running fine ([http://azuretest.azurewebsites.net](http://azuretest.azurewebsits.net))

I downloaded the Publish profile from Windows Azure and import it in Visual Studio. When I publish the website I select to publish the database, select the right connection string (from the publish profile).

After publishing I get this error:

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete an operation
>   with the specified provider ("dbSqlPackage") when connecting using the
>   Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has
>   not authorized the user for this operation. dbSqlPackage
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DEPLOYMENTPROVIDER.)      0   0   azuretest

The url's in this error message links to articles from 2008 and 2010. I don't think that I can find any good info there..

The error says

> This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user
>   for this operation

but I don't think I can authorize anything on a shared Windows Azure Website, can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered this at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/3f99e1e3-e030-47e0-9e43-f029663ca806.

Hi Marcel, I work on the Visual Studio Web team. When we released VS 2012 RC we had the hopes that we would be able to finalize the server side components of the Update Database checkbox by the time that the RC went out. Unfortunately we were not able to do that, so the Update Database checkbox in VS 2012 RC only works if you are publshing to localhost.

We are working to get the server side pieces ready but we cannot commit to a schedule yet. I've blogged about this at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2012/06/14/vs-publish-dialog-update-database-dialog-disabled.aspx.